# Can't connect to work PC using computer name but can using IP address via Microsoft Remote Desktop app

Tags: remote-desktop

I can connect to my work desktop PC (Win 10 pro) located in my workplace room with my iPad Pro (iOS 16) from another room (connected to the same LAN) via the desktop PC's local IP address (e.g. 192.168.x.x) but can't connect by using its computer name.

I want to fix this problem since otherwise every time I have to check the local IP address and edit it on iPad Pro which is very tiring.

What could be the possible reasons and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you able to connect if you add `.local` to the name?

Comment: @u1686_grawity It worked perfectly! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What could be the possible reasons and how do I fix it?

There are approximately four methods to look up a local hostname – your router is responsible for one of them not working right, while the others are a bit of a mess.

One of them would be internal DNS (your router taking the PC's hostname from DHCP and remembering it); this likely doesn't work for the same reason that your computer keeps getting different addresses every time – your router can't remember issued leases for some reason. (Most routers are capable of always issuing the same IP to the same PC.)

The other mechanisms work without a router, but for *bare* names there actually aren't any in common between Windows and iOS. (There's Windows' old NETBIOS, which macOS did support but I don't think iOS ever did, and in any case it's obsolete and even Windows itself no longer offers it by default – and then there's Windows' LLMNR, which Apple products never really supported at all.)

The one last mechanism that's in common between your PC and your iPad is Apple's mDNS, which is built-in to macOS and iOS and which recent versions of Windows 10/11 will in fact respond to. (Android 1x also supports it.) However, per its design, mDNS isn't used for bare names – it's used for names under the `.local` domain, and while Windows bends this rule, iOS sticks to it.

So in short, you'll have to use `MyComputer.local` for this to work (through mDNS), *or* figure out why your router doesn't remember the DHCP leases and doesn't serve DNS according to them.